# How can I use a custom font for displaying Emojis in Google Colab using Seaborn graphs

Tags: matplotlib, fonts, seaborn, google-colaboratory, emoji

I'm making a study about the use of emojis on Brazilian Twitter, I've manage to extract the data from the Twitter and made a pandas DataFrame that looks like this.

```
index,emojis
,75
,66
,55
,35
,32
,25
,18
,18
,17
❤,15
```

The thing is that Seaborn default font does not have all the emojis, so my graph ends up looking something like this:

```
sns.barplot(x = data.index, y="emojis",data=data)
```

[seaborn graph with a bad display of emojis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KfAA.png)

```
!wget "https://fonts.google.com/download?family=Noto%20Color%20Emoji"
!mv font_file.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
!unzip "download?family=Noto Color Emoji"

!fc-cache -f -v
```

```
#the error I get
mv: cannot stat 'font_file.ttf': No such file or directory
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 2 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/humor-sans: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation: caching, new cache contents: 16 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/root/.local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/root/.fonts: skipping, no such directory
/var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/root/.cache/fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
/root/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
```

I tried this two methods that I've found here in stack overflow, The first one written above, I get an error "mv: cannot stat 'font_file.ttf': No such file or directory", that i have no idea how to solve.

```
!wget https://fonts.google.com/download?family=Noto%20Color%20Emoji -P /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf

matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()
matplotlib.rc('font', family='Noto Color Emoji')
```

This second method did not gave me any errors but didn't change the font, maybe I'm missing a function to define the font for the graph, as I am using seaborn for the graph but changing the font on Matplotlib, but in my understanding it should work as seaborn is built over matplotlib.

If someone can shine a light in this problem I'll be very thankful for the help as I tried multiple suggestion from Stack overflow, using vs code in my computer and using Google Colab on the cloud, I could not change the fonts to display Emojis on my graph in either way, so my last resort was to ask a question here.